# Do DNS servers get queried in round-robin, random or some other fashion?

Tags: nameserver, dns-hosting, domain-name-system

I know for a fact that `A` records and most other records are round-robin. `MX` records have priority types.
What about D(NS) servers? Both in the context of `NS` record and static configuration in client systems. Which order do they get used/called?

Comment: The initial choice of NS is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common nameservers (e.g. BIND) will do a lock on mechanism by which the resolver measures the round trip time to each target nameserver and locks on to the one with the fastest response time. This is generally the closest nameserver.

> Each time a BIND nameserver sends a query to a remote nameserver, it starts an internal stopwatch. When it receives a response, it stops the stopwatch and makes a note of how long that remote nameserver took to respond. -- DNS and Bind 5th edition, Liu and Albitz

Another namerserver, djbdns, simply [chooses a random server](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/notes.html). More details in this [paper](http://dns.measurement-factory.com/writings/wessels-pam2004-paper.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically they had to be round-robin, too.

But the main problem is that their query depends not on your configuration, but on the induvidual features of the remote DNS services. They are not always configured properly, and they are mostly not the best known software. Practically, you can't wait this behavior from them. This is because you practically can't make a redundant system by multiple NS hosts.

Lukcily, most of them have enough brain to query the alternate DNS is there is no answer from the first, but even that isn't always so.